# What is the best way to backup mysql in s3?

Tags: mysql, scripting, backup, amazon-s3

mysqldump is probably not the best idea on running backups every x hours but is the one that we are currently using.  The backups are around 150 Megs each so sending it to other machines could waste many gigs of bandwidth.

Is there any tool or application or script that could automate the creation of the backup and the upload to s3 amazon service or any similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Zmanda Enterprise](http://www.zmanda.com/backup-Amazon-S3.html) offers backup to S3.

Comment: I am checking out this software, apparently the option for S3 backup is with the enterprise edition.  Have you tested backup for S3 with the community edition?

Answer (score 1):

Either you set up the LVM and/or a back-up slave.

```
On the target machine:
mysql> STOP SLAVE -- if a back-up slave is used
mysql> FLUSH TABLES READ LOCK
^Z
% lvm_snapshot_blah blah-blah on /mnt/backup_image  
% fg
mysql> UNLOCK TABLES
mysql> START SLAVE -- if a back-up slave is used
^Z
% mount /mnt/backup_image /mnt/backup
% s3upload_recursively /mnt/backup/mysql_data https://s3.amazon.com/blah_blah
```

Comment: The s3upload_recursively is that an inhouse script or that is a generic term?  I am just wondering how you were able to upload with that command.

Comment: I just made that up like s3upload_recursively_blah_blah. You could use http://code.google.com/p/s3-bash/ . But it doesn't support recursive uploading.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to save space and bandwidth is to only backup the tables that were updated.

I found this by accident, but it looks like a good starting point for a backup script:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, UPDATE_TIME, CREATE_TIME
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name' AND UPDATE_TIME > CREATE_TIME;
```